# Git says my .gitignore path is invalid and can't be added

Tags: git

I have a very simple problem, and I don't understand what's wrong. I'm trying to stage my .gitignore file for commit, but Git says the path is invalid. Plain as that. My terminal output is pasted below. As you can see, the .gitignore file is indeed there, but I can't add it.

```
magnus@magnus:~/Documents/deep-rl-hex$ git status
On branch neural_net_added
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/neural_net_added'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean


magnus@magnus:~/Documents/deep-rl-hex$ ls -alt .git/
    total 68
    drwxr-xr-x   8 magnus magnus 4096 nov.  13 17:48 .
    -rw-r--r--   1 magnus magnus 2436 nov.  13 17:48 index
    -rw-r--r--   1 magnus magnus   41 nov.  13 17:48 ORIG_HEAD
    drwxr-xr-x   5 magnus magnus 4096 nov.  13 17:48 refs
    drwxr-xr-x 160 magnus magnus 4096 nov.  13 17:48 objects
    -rw-r--r--   1 magnus magnus 1427 nov.  13 17:39 .gitignore #.gitignore file is indeed here
    drwxr-xr-x   5 magnus magnus 4096 nov.  13 17:38 ..
    -rw-r--r--   1 magnus magnus   33 nov.  13 17:38 HEAD
    -rw-r--r--   1 magnus magnus  221 nov.  13 17:38 FETCH_HEAD
    -rw-r--r--   1 magnus magnus  348 nov.  13 17:28 config
    -rw-r--r--   1 magnus magnus    4 nov.  13 17:27 COMMIT_EDITMSG
    drwxr-xr-x   3 magnus magnus 4096 okt.  27 14:35 logs
    -rw-r--r--   1 magnus magnus  114 okt.  27 14:35 packed-refs
    drwxr-xr-x   2 magnus magnus 4096 okt.  27 14:35 hooks
    drwxr-xr-x   2 magnus magnus 4096 okt.  27 14:35 info
    drwxr-xr-x   2 magnus magnus 4096 okt.  27 14:35 branches
    -rw-r--r--   1 magnus magnus   73 okt.  27 14:35 description


magnus@magnus:~/Documents/deep-rl-hex$ git add .git/.gitignore
    error: Invalid path '.git/.gitignore'
    error: unable to add .git/.gitignore to index
    fatal: adding files failed
```

What is the problem here? It's quite obviously something elementary I'm missing, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.gitignore` file, like all other files in your working tree, belongs outside the `.git` directory.  `git add` doesn't apply to the files in `.git`.

Answer (score 2):

adding a file inside the .git directory. That's a `no no`.